# Estimating an OLS model in R with million observations and thousands of variables

Tags: r, bigdata, limit

I am trying to estimate a big OLS regression with ~1 million observations and ~50,000 variables using biglm.

I am planning to run each estimation using chunks of approximately 100 observations each.  I tested this strategy with a small sample and it worked fine.

However, with the real data I am getting an "Error: protect(): protection stack overflow"  when trying to define the formula for the biglm function.

I've already tried:

- starting R with --max-ppsize=50000
- setting options(expressions = 50000)

but the error persists

I am working on Windows and using Rstudio

```
# create the sample data frame (In my true case, I simply select 100 lines from the original data that contains ~1,000,000 lines)
DF <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=100,ncol=50000))
DF[,] <- rnorm(100*50000)
colnames(DF) <- c("y", paste0("x", seq(1:49999)))

# get names of covariates
my_xvars <- colnames(DF)[2:( ncol(DF) )]

# define the formula to be used in biglm
# HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR :
my_f <- as.formula(paste("y~", paste(my_xvars, collapse = " + ")))
```

**EDIT 1:**
The ultimate goal of my exercise is to estimate the average effect of all 50,000 variables. Therefore, simplifying the model selecting fewer variables is not the solution I am looking for now.

Comment: what are you looking to get out of a 50,000 variable model? it might be worth looking into dimension reduction techniques before you model.

Comment: You may want to use other methods than OLS, like penalized regression which can cope with many (correlated) predictors better than OLS http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/37-model-selection-essentials-in-r/153-penalized-regression-essentials-ridge-lasso-elastic-net/

Comment: The ultimate goal of my exercise is indeed to estimate the average effect of each of the 50,000 covariates in the dependent variable.  Therefore, simplifying the model with fewer variables is not an ideal solution.

I am already splitting the estimation using chunks of rows.  It would be awesome if there was any way to separate the estimation using subsets of columns as well, and then being able to recover an unbiased estimate for the effect of each variable, however I couldn't find anything like that yet.

Comment: This doesn't seem valid since the coefficient of each variable also depents onn what other variables are in the model. Thus the mean coefficient of 2 diifferent models can be quite different compared to the mean coefficient one model with all the variables.

Comment: @igoR87 you are absolutely right, feature space partitioning seems to be much more complicated than sample space partitioning.  I found the thesis below from a Duke student that suggests a set of solutions for this type of problem.  However, before trying to implement (and to understand) something like that, I was hoping that maybe there is a solution more easily available already

https://dukespace.lib.duke.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/10161/12912/Wang_duke_0066D_13692.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

Comment: It seems unlikely you wouldn't have multicollinearity issues dealing with 50K variables.

Comment: As for your error, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first bottleneck (I can't guarantee there won't be others) is in the construction of the formula.  R can't construct a formula that long from text (details are too ugly to explore right now).  Below I show a hacked version of the `biglm` code that can take the model matrix `X` and response variable `y` directly, rather than using a formula to build them. **However**: the next bottleneck is that the internal function `biglm:::bigqr.init()`, which gets called inside `biglm`, tries to allocate a numeric vector of size `choose(nc,2)=nc*(nc-1)/2` (where `nc` is the number of columns. When I try with 50000 columns I get

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 9.3 Gb

(2.3Gb are required when `nc` is 25000). The code below runs on my laptop when `nc <- 10000`.

I have a few caveats about this approach:

- you won't be able to handle a probelm with 50000 columns unless you have at least 10G of memory, because of the issue described above.
- the `biglm:::update.biglm` will have to be modified in a parallel way (this shouldn't be too hard)
- I have **no idea if the p>>n issue (which applies at the level of fitting the initial chunk) will bite you**.  When running my example below (with 10 rows, 10000 columns), all but 10 of the parameters are `NA`. I don't know if these `NA` values will contaminate the results so that successive updating fails. If so, I don't know if there's a way to work around the problem, or if it's fundamental (so that you would need `nr>nc` for at least the initial fit). (It would be straightforward to do some small experiments to see if there is a problem, but I've already spent too long on this ...)
- don't forget that with this approach you have to explicitly add an intercept column to the model matrix (e.g. `X <- cbind(1,X)` if you want one.

---

Example (first save the code at the bottom as `my_biglm.R`):

```
nr <- 10
nc <- 10000
DF <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(nr*nc),nrow=nr))

respvars <- paste0("x", seq(nc-1))
names(DF) <- c("y", respvars)

# illustrate formula problem: fails somewhere in 15000 < nc < 20000
try(reformulate(respvars,response="y"))

source("my_biglm.R")
rr <- my_biglm(y=DF[,1],X=as.matrix(DF[,-1]))
```

---

```
my_biglm <- function (formula, data, weights = NULL, sandwich = FALSE,
                      y=NULL, X=NULL, off=0) {
    if (!is.null(weights)) {
        if (!inherits(weights, "formula")) 
            stop("`weights' must be a formula")
        w <- model.frame(weights, data)[[1]]
    } else w <- NULL
    if (is.null(X)) {
        tt <- terms(formula)
        mf <- model.frame(tt, data)
        if (is.null(off <- model.offset(mf))) 
            off <- 0
        mm <- model.matrix(tt, mf)
        y <- model.response(mf) - off
    } else {
        ## model matrix specified directly
        if (is.null(y)) stop("both y and X must be specified")
        mm <- X
        tt <- NULL
    }
    qr <- biglm:::bigqr.init(NCOL(mm))
    qr <- biglm:::update.bigqr(qr, mm, y, w)
    rval <- list(call = sys.call(), qr = qr, assign = attr(mm, 
        "assign"), terms = tt, n = NROW(mm), names = colnames(mm), 
        weights = weights)
    if (sandwich) {
        p <- ncol(mm)
        n <- nrow(mm)
        xyqr <- bigqr.init(p * (p + 1))
        xx <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = p * (p + 1))
        xx[, 1:p] <- mm * y
        for (i in 1:p) xx[, p * i + (1:p)] <- mm * mm[, i]
        xyqr <- update(xyqr, xx, rep(0, n), w * w)
        rval$sandwich <- list(xy = xyqr)
    }
    rval$df.resid <- rval$n - length(qr$D)
    class(rval) <- "biglm"
    rval
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  The formula limit was solved. But, as you expected, I ran into RAM limit with 50k vars.

About your points 1 & 3:
-I dont have 10G available

- About the p>n within chunks, I tested with my data a reduced version of the problem (1k rows, 200 vars, 50rows/chunk), and the chunked estimation returned the same results as estimating all at once.  However, my real data is sparse (>80% zeros).  I then tested it with a dense matrix, and results are very different, with chunked estimation returning lots of NAs

I will look for alternative solutions to my problem